# How to change plugged in power setting in tlp to the same as on battery

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

Recently, I got an dell XPS 9560 and installed Ubuntu linux, but the coil whine when the machine is plugged in is driving me crazy. I'm pretty new to linux, and installed tlp to improve battery life. I suspect the issue is due to the amount of power supplied to the CPU, but am not certain. Since there's no sound when on battery, is there a way to set the plugged in setting to the same as when on battery, and allow one to switch is back if necessary?